# Work items associated with releases

Tags: ms-release-management

I have a vNext release that is triggered by a gated check-in build. The associated changeset is linked with an work item.

What I have to check in order to have the linked work item displayed in the Change Summary tab of the release as in [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/08/05/work-items-tracking-using-release-management.aspx)?

Comment: Can you give some more information? What is not working for you? This will not work for builds externally components. Also, can you see the changesets have been associated to the build correctly?

Comment: I was expecting to see the associated work items that are displayed in the build summary also in the release summary.
the release template is using a component with "Builds with application" set.