# How to view Work Items associated with a Release in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193673/work-items-associated-with-releases) but for Azure DevOps. Going back 6-12 months, I was able to open a deployed Release (or possibly a successful Build, my memory is hazy) in what was then VSTS and view the backlog Work Items associated with it. On that page I was also able to filter on release names so that the list would show me all Work Items associated with any Release from the same Release Definition that was newer than the one I filtered on. This was how I used to put together our user-friendly release notes. It allowed me to view the bugs that'd been fixed, the features that'd been included, and so on. As far as I can tell, this feature no longer exists in Azure DevOps - at least, I can't find it.

The closest I can get is to view a list of Changesets from a particular date in the Changesets pivot, but that's not as comprehensive as a list of Work Items that were completed, and also doesn't tell me which Release those Changesets were included in.

I can also run a Query to show Work Items completed from a particular date but again I don't think I can view what Releases those Work Items were associated with, and even if I could it wouldn't help much unless I could filter Work Items based on the repository branch from which the Release was created.

Does anybody know if there is a way now in Azure DevOps to view the Work Items associated with a particular Release or Build? And, ideally, a list of Work Items associated with any Build or Release created from a specified Build or Release Definition from a particular date (e.g. "Show me all Work Items associated with Builds created from the 'Education Only Version' Build Definition since January 1st").

Comment: I asked a similar question a little bit before you on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079335/azure-devops-pipeline-get-work-items-between-builds .  still no great answers

Answer (score 3):

Howzit

Edit: I just realized this question was long ago... it showed near the top, assuming you have this solution but now

When you deploy a stage you can see all the work items and commits that are linked to commits since the last build that went to that stage.

[image]